# Laravel form with jquery only shows plain text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel

i'm having troubles inserting html on my form with JQuery, i have a button that via jquery adds a new div with a laravelcollective select input, the add works fine but my laravelcollective select input only shows a plain text, it is possible to do this? or i should put a pure HTML tag on my jquery code..
I attach a image and my code below, ty for ur replies..

[image: Screenshow]

```
$(document).on('click','.btn-add-drink',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$("#begin1").after("<div class='form-group option-container'>
    <div class='control-label col-md-2'></div>
    <div class='col-md-5 pull-left' id='addDrinks' >
    {!!Form::select('bebidas', $bebidas,null,['id'=>'select1','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Seleccione una bebida..','required'])!!}
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-2'>
    <button class='btn btn-danger btn-remove' onclick='deleteElement()' data-tooltip='Quitar elemento'><b>X</b></button>
    </div>
    </div>");
```

});

Comment: Are you trying to use Blade in a javascript file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your form file extension is .blade.php

Try adding a @ in front of your blade statements.

If that doesn't work, try using {{ }} instead of {!! !!}

Comment: Are you sure you have your formfile  extension as .blade.php and not .php?

Comment: Oh ok ! i put the extension '.js' (so dummy) i renamed it to ''.blade.php" and it works, but my question is: is it secure? i put my jquery code between script html tag, and it is visible, is there any way to show laravelcollective forms without use blade? i guess using only html tags is it right?

Comment: I've only ever used it with blade, so probably not. However, even if you use plain html elements within the Blade form, it will still post. So you can go down that route if you want.